# Android Studio unable to import functions from .JAR file in lib folder

Tags: android

I'm total Android newbie here. I am following a link to generate a QR code and here is the [link](https://backendless.com/how-to-generate-a-qr-code-with-backendless-api-service/). I followed the instruction and when I reach step 3 , the code fails to import the **JAR** file from `src` folder.

Here is the library imports that fails:

```
import com.backendless.Backendless;
import com.backendless.servercode.BackendlessService;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
```

Here is the screenshot of my project:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any explanation on how does this happen?

I really want to know what's went wrong in my project here. I would really appreciate anyone who can explain this issue to me, or at least give me some tips to search on Google.

Comment: can you post your gradle as well, settings,build.grad;e

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your jar file and select **Add As Library**

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your jar libraries are inside `libs` directory, so please ensure that you add below dependency into your `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}
```

Synchronise your project again to get your project refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on **File > Project Structure >Select app > Dependencies Tab.**
2. Click on **(+) plus button** given on right side and select **File Dependency.**
3. This will pop up a dialog box for selecting path. Under this open **libs** folder and add your Jar files one by one.
4. Once you select all three Jar files then click Ok button and your Gradle will Start building.